# Overflow:hidden bug in Firefox26 on windows 7

Tags: html, css, firefox, windows-7

A curious bug in Firefox that only occurs in a very specific environment, namely Firefox version 26 on Windows 7 SP1 machines (confirmed on at least two different computers). This bug does not occur on Firefox 26 on Windows 8, and neither does it occur on Firefox 25.x on Windows 7.

The actual bug, as you can see from the screenshot below is that the text in the treeview control is breaking out of the container which has an overflow:hidden defined on it.

Image on Firefox 26 on Windows 7:
[image]

Image on Firefox 26 on Windows 8:
[image]

What I have tried

- Messing with the overflow settings using firebug, no effect.
- Minor changes to the structure, no effect.

The treeview is a Kendo UI treeview, and the site in general is using Bootstrap 2.x as the base CSS. No other browser has shown this problem.

EDIT:

[jsFiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/2DF8w/4/) Make sure to expand the result window wide enough to make the treeview visible (it is hidden on smaller screens). The html may be a bit sloppy because I tried to slice out anything unnecessary, but still had to leave an awful lot of fluff in just to avoid removing the issue itself.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="koulutuspuuApp">
            <h4>Course plan<small> Kakku Kondiittori Petri</small></h4>
            <div id="koulutuspuuContent" style="display: block;">
                <div class="rq-overflowOuterContainer" style="">
                    <div class="rq-overflowInnerContainer"><div class="rq-slidingNavElement">
                        <div class="rq-pyoristettyLaatikko rq-koulutusPuu k-widget k-treeview" data-role="treeview" tabindex="0" role="tree"><ul role="group" class="k-group k-treeview-lines"><li data-uid="b57674b6-2f39-42f0-a109-34d09eed91b6" class="k-item k-first" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-top"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Network structure.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKoulutusnimike1281">Kakku Kondiittori Petri</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="3b625cf9-d5ee-4054-995e-047e976b4ca4" class="k-item" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-top"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/folder_green_1641_16.png" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuModuuli28430">Kondiittoriatuotannon hallinta</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="00f4fcf5-c113-429d-8b6e-06b473b41e41" class="k-item" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-top"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi28456">Kondiittoriatuontantokurssi 1/3</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="de7f35ca-e2da-4f2f-a263-32e1ace87b27" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-bot"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55423">vcbcvbcvb</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="0d087736-84c0-4a55-b657-5666966341f9" class="k-item" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-top"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55439">cxxxxxccxxcxcxc</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="36cd3597-9294-4ba5-bb54-3c57b59262a5" class="k-item" role="treeitem"><div class="k-top"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/sininen_certificate_16.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuNaytto57242">Näyttö 1 test mod</span></span></div></li><li data-uid="5fe55e00-34d9-4f1b-9fbc-89626196add1" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-bot"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55495">dcdccdcd</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="9afc1861-eff3-48d4-a15f-6d2cfb53b507" class="k-item" role="treeitem"><div class="k-top"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi56790">Miika test element 1 reaaaaaalallllllllyyy looong naaaaammmeee</span></span></div></li><li data-uid="8d91ab7f-192f-4047-870e-985931dad764" class="k-item" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-mid"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi56781">Kääretortut osa 2</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="20acc5b8-7d34-4be2-b7d5-1d0f89b2529e" class="k-item" role="treeitem"><div class="k-top"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi16851"> <i class="icon-resize-small"></i> 1.5. Osaamistavoite 1.5</span></span></div></li><li data-uid="1e0d49dc-7806-4226-b944-da5cb4d183e0" class="k-item" role="treeitem"><div class="k-mid"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi54006"> <i class="icon-resize-small"></i> 1.6 Osaamistavoite 1.6</span></span></div></li><li data-uid="b8ba689a-9fe1-4e97-a23c-5d634efee1aa" class="k-item" role="treeitem"><div class="k-mid"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi16854"> <i class="icon-resize-small"></i> 1.7 Osaamistavoite 1.7</span></span></div></li><li data-uid="0e65587f-6d51-4034-bb79-2ddbc3758452" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem"><div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi29863"> <i class="icon-resize-small"></i> Eräopas kurssi II</span></span></div></li></ul></li><li data-uid="a09ca0d9-0c5e-4d66-ab57-fcb0273063b1" class="k-item" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-mid"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55994">cxxxxxccxxcxcxc</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="07d4f591-35e1-4599-ac8d-b4049b64ed01" class="k-item" role="treeitem"><div class="k-top"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi56797"> <i class="icon-resize-small"></i> Kurssi 2</span></span></div></li><li data-uid="96695918-0cad-4ad3-ac96-387f8070b8b3" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem"><div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi56801"> <i class="icon-resize-small"></i> Kurssi 123</span></span></div></li></ul></li><li data-uid="fbc3e9f9-866e-4db4-af8e-d3fa3f8834d4" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem"><div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi56791">Miika test element 2</span></span></div></li></ul></li></ul></li><li data-uid="32b7b7f3-95de-461f-8d85-93bbb7b3f753" class="k-item" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-mid"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55440">cxxxxxccxxcxcxc</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="e9bce69e-877e-494a-a779-fad8c45f70aa" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-bot"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55494">dcdccdcd</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="43b51666-e055-4516-b154-9df5507ab0e9" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem"><div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55993">cxxxxxccxxcxcxc</span></span></div></li></ul></li></ul></li><li data-uid="f63d2da6-59a3-4e44-9bd8-71770a1e1de0" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true"><div class="k-bot"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55441">cxxxxxccxxcxcxc</span></span></div><ul role="group" class="k-group" style="display: block;"><li data-uid="a02a244b-bd1d-4021-8c79-73dc0779836d" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem"><div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi55992">cxxxxxccxxcxcxc</span></span></div></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li data-uid="1b3a56d7-89e9-41ff-91e6-8becde2cd31d" class="k-item k-last" role="treeitem"><div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><img src="/campus/kuvat/Yellow pin.gif" alt="" class="k-image"><span id="kpuuKurssi28457">Kondiittoriatuontantokurssi 2/3</span></span></div></li></ul></li></li></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="rq-staticNavElement">
                         <div class="rq-navContent" style="display: block;">
                             <div class="alert alert-info">      
                                 <h5>Welcome to the administration of course plans</h5>
                                 <p>Thru the course plan administration .... </p>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also reported as a [Firefox bug.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=953253)

Comment: Now what exactly do you expect from stackoverflow? If you're certain it's a bug, it's better to submit to the firefox bug tracker. If you want other people to check if the bug occurs on their machines as well, you should provide a link to test it.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Added a jsFiddle that shows the issue. I am not certain it is a bug, or just something I have done wrong. The stackoverflow community has in the past been quite good about figuring it out either way, or at least pointing out a way forward. Will submit it to the firefox bug tracker also though.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Also reported as a firefox bug, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=953253 . Seems that it has been confirmed as well, at least under some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like on my screen - as far as i can tell, it's correct.

[image: output of jsfiddle]

My firefox is a (german) 26.0:

[image]

and i'm running Windows 7 SP 1:

[image]

Sorry for the image spam, but i think it was neccesary here to make sure there's no misunderstanding in versions.

Have you checked/disabled your addons?

Comment: Hmm, that is quite curious! It does in fact show up correctly on yours. I've tested it on two separate machines at the office, and both had the same issue. One machine had an older version of FF, and it worked fine, but once FF was updated to 26, then it broke. Neither machine has any FF addons installed. The only difference I can see is that you have the Ultimate version, and I think we had something lower.. perhaps Enterprise?